# signing up google computing engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Can I ask about google computing engine is this service has free account ?. I have read in online docs it says `$300 credit for free` . so how many months I can use the free service ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use a very basic VM you have it **completely free**. These are the requirements for the free tier:

- 1 f1-micro VM instance per month (US regions, excluding Northern Virginia).
- 30 GB of HDD persistent disk storage per month.
- 5 GB of snapshot storage per month.
- 1 GB egress from North America to other destinations per month (excluding Australia and China).

https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing

If you use the 300$ voucher you have it for **1 year**. https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-trial
You can spend it all in a week or a month or a year, depending on which machines you run.

Comment: Does anyone has any idea why Northern Virginia is excluded? I'm not from there, just curious.